# Pig oozie workflow does not execute UDF

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I am trying to execute pig script containing UDFs through Oozie and stores result into postgress tables .Without oozie script runs perfectly.
With oozie the script executes successfully but does not generate required data into postgress.Logs show this warning

2015-08-18 12:05:44,709 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats  - unable to find the output file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://:8020/user/oozie/word_cnt does not exist.

Doing trial and error I found if I put dump statements after every "store", the data is stored in postgress successfully.

Comment: do plz share the workflow.xml of ur oozie job

Comment: Code not getting aligned on multiple lines, but here is the workflow:
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="helloworld_pig_wk">
<start to="pig-node"/>
<action name="pig-node">
<pig>
<job-tracker><jobtracker>:8050</job-tracker>
<name-node><namenode>:8020</name-node>
<script>helloworld.pig</script>
<argument>stop_on_failure</argument>
<argument>b</argument>
<argument>M</argument>
</pig>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="fail"/>
    </action>

Comment: Please could you add it into the original text rather than here? That way it can be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong the Workflow.xml seems some value missing {jobTracker} {NameNode}.

The Sammple Workflow.xml will be like

```
<action name="pigActionForData">
<pig>
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
<value>default</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
<value>default</value>
</property>
</configuration>
<script>PigScript.pig</script>
<argument>-param</argument>
<argument>PigInput=/HDFS/LOCATION/FOR/PIG/ONLY/REFERENCE</argument>
</pig>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="pigActionForDataFailed"/>
</action>
<kill name="pigActionForDataFailed">
<message>Pig Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
```

You can all directrly mention

> {jobtracker} = "jobtracker_ip:port"
>
> {namenode}="hdfs://namenode_ip:port"

Comment: Sorry about that.The values are present  in actual workflow i had jus removed the ipaddress.The jobs completes successfully but the data is not written.

Comment: on that case, you check the Logic of Ur Pig Script, by processing sample Data, these will help to figure the status of ur job :)